Pairs of consecutive numbers all whose prime divisiors come from a pre-specified finite set
What is known about the following problem?

Let $S$ be finite set of prime numbers. Find all pairs $(n, n+1)$ of consecutive numbers where all prime divisors of $n$ and all prime divisors of $n + 1$ lie in the set $S$.

If the abc-conjecture is true there are only finitely many such pairs for each set $S$.
My questions is:

Is there an unconditional proof that there are only finitely many pairs, and can we give a concrete upper bound (depending on $S$) on their number?

I would not be surprised if this was solved already in the 18th or 19th century, but I find it hard to find information online as google keeps returning stuff about consecutive prime numbers rather than consecutive integers.

This question is similar to: Finite amount of consecutive smooth numbers. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem. I used a site search to find Is there an integer $y>0$ such that for all $x>y$, at least $4$ of $x+1, x+2, x+3, x+4, x+5$ are divisible by a prime greater than $5$?. ...

(cont.) This answer there led me Wikipedia's Størmer's theorem article. After reading to confirm that it's basically what you're asking about, I then did another site search for this theorem, from which I found the proposed duplicate.

Thanks the linked question seems just what I was looking for!
